# Python machine learning Naive Bayes classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I have little data set which i want to test Naive Bayes classification using python i tried alot different methods but code wont run and i didnt got expected output so finally i thought here someone will figure out my problem

i have huge data set sample data set is attached for testing i want to test Naive Bayes classification in python machine learning.

my dataset link http://www.wikisend.com/download/663276/

Answer (score 2):

This is a fully functioning code, from Jason Brownlee, Machine Learning Mastery, that I have adapted for your needs by removing the csv file and embedding the data in the file as a matrix.

I've bought several of his books and have implemented some time series prediction techniques of his in my daily work on the job.

The following code produces this output below and you can structure your process as follows:

> /usr/local/bin/python3.8
>   /Users/fisheyjay/PycharmProjects/naive_bayes_iris/naive_bayes_iris.py
>   Scores: [93.33333333333333, 96.66666666666667, 100.0,
>   93.33333333333333, 93.33333333333333] Mean Accuracy: 95.333%
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

and here is the code:

```
# Naive Bayes On The Iris iris_data_set
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from math import sqrt
from math import exp
from math import pi


# Convert string column to float
def str_column_to_float(iris_data_set, column):
    for row in iris_data_set:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())


# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(iris_data_set, column):
    class_values = [row[column] for row in iris_data_set]
    unique = set(class_values)
    lookup = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
    for row in iris_data_set:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup


# Split a iris_data_set into k folds
def cross_validation_split(iris_data_set, n_folds):
    iris_data_set_split = list()
    iris_data_set_copy = list(iris_data_set)
    fold_size = int(len(iris_data_set) / n_folds)
    for _ in range(n_folds):
        fold = list()
        while len(fold) < fold_size:
            index = randrange(len(iris_data_set_copy))
            fold.append(iris_data_set_copy.pop(index))
        iris_data_set_split.append(fold)
    return iris_data_set_split


# Calculate accuracy percentage
def accuracy_metric(actual, predicted):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(actual)):
        if actual[i] == predicted[i]:
            correct += 1
    return correct / float(len(actual)) * 100.0


# Evaluate an algorithm using a cross validation split
def evaluate_algorithm(iris_data_set, algorithm, n_folds, *args):
    folds = cross_validation_split(iris_data_set, n_folds)
    scores = list()
    for fold in folds:
        train_set = list(folds)
        train_set.remove(fold)
        train_set = sum(train_set, [])
        test_set = list()
        for row in fold:
            row_copy = list(row)
            test_set.append(row_copy)
            row_copy[-1] = None
        predicted = algorithm(train_set, test_set, *args)
        actual = [row[-1] for row in fold]
        accuracy = accuracy_metric(actual, predicted)
        scores.append(accuracy)
    return scores


# Split the iris_data_set by class values, returns a dictionary
def separate_by_class(iris_data_set):
    separated = dict()
    for i in range(len(iris_data_set)):
        vector = iris_data_set[i]
        class_value = vector[-1]
        if (class_value not in separated):
            separated[class_value] = list()
        separated[class_value].append(vector)
    return separated


# Calculate the mean of a list of numbers
def mean(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))


# Calculate the standard deviation of a list of numbers
def standard_deviation(numbers):
    avg = mean(numbers)
    variance = sum([(x - avg) ** 2 for x in numbers]) / float(len(numbers) - 1)
    return sqrt(variance)


# Calculate the mean, standard_deviation and count for each column in a iris_data_set
def summarize_iris_data_set(iris_data_set):
    summaries = [(mean(column), standard_deviation(column), len(column)) for column in zip(*iris_data_set)]
    del (summaries[-1])
    return summaries


# Split iris_data_set by class then calculate statistics for each row
def summarize_by_class(iris_data_set):
    separated = separate_by_class(iris_data_set)
    summaries = dict()
    for class_value, rows in separated.items():
        summaries[class_value] = summarize_iris_data_set(rows)
    return summaries


# Calculate the Gaussian probability distribution function for x
def calculate_probability(x, mean, standard_deviation):
    exponent = exp(-((x - mean) ** 2 / (2 * standard_deviation ** 2)))
    return (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * standard_deviation)) * exponent


# Calculate the probabilities of predicting each class for a given row
def calculate_class_probabilities(summaries, row):
    total_rows = sum([summaries[label][0][2] for label in summaries])
    probabilities = dict()
    for class_value, class_summaries in summaries.items():
        probabilities[class_value] = summaries[class_value][0][2] / float(total_rows)
        for i in range(len(class_summaries)):
            mean, standard_deviation, _ = class_summaries[i]
            probabilities[class_value] *= calculate_probability(row[i], mean, standard_deviation)
    return probabilities


# Predict the class for a given row
def predict(summaries, row):
    probabilities = calculate_class_probabilities(summaries, row)
    best_label, best_prob = None, -1
    for class_value, probability in probabilities.items():
        if best_label is None or probability > best_prob:
            best_prob = probability
            best_label = class_value
    return best_label


# Naive Bayes Algorithm
def naive_bayes(train, test):
    summarize = summarize_by_class(train)
    predictions = list()
    for row in test:
        output = predict(summarize, row)
        predictions.append(output)
    return (predictions)


# Test Naive Bayes on Iris iris_data_set
seed(1)

iris_data_set = [['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.7', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.6', '3.1', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.0', '3.6', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.4', '3.9', '1.7', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.6', '3.4', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.0', '3.4', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.4', '2.9', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.9', '3.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.4', '3.7', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.8', '3.4', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.8', '3.0', '1.4', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.3', '3.0', '1.1', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.8', '4.0', '1.2', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.7', '4.4', '1.5', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.4', '3.9', '1.3', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.7', '3.8', '1.7', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.1', '3.8', '1.5', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.4', '3.4', '1.7', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.1', '3.7', '1.5', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.6', '3.6', '1.0', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.1', '3.3', '1.7', '0.5', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.8', '3.4', '1.9', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.0', '3.4', '1.6', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.2', '3.5', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.2', '3.4', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.7', '3.2', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.8', '3.1', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.4', '3.4', '1.5', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.2', '4.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.5', '4.2', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.9', '3.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.0', '3.2', '1.2', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.5', '3.5', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.9', '3.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.4', '3.0', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.1', '3.4', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.0', '3.5', '1.3', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.5', '2.3', '1.3', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['4.4', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.0', '3.5', '1.6', '0.6', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.1', '3.8', '1.9', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.8', '3.0', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.1', '3.8', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.6', '3.2', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['5.3', '3.7', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['5.0', '3.3', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
     ['7.0', '3.2', '4.7', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.4', '3.2', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.9', '3.1', '4.9', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.5', '2.3', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.5', '2.8', '4.6', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.7', '2.8', '4.5', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.3', '3.3', '4.7', '1.6', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['4.9', '2.4', '3.3', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.6', '2.9', '4.6', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.2', '2.7', '3.9', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.0', '2.0', '3.5', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.9', '3.0', '4.2', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.0', '2.2', '4.0', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.1', '2.9', '4.7', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.6', '2.9', '3.6', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.7', '3.1', '4.4', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.6', '3.0', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.8', '2.7', '4.1', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.2', '2.2', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.6', '2.5', '3.9', '1.1', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.9', '3.2', '4.8', '1.8', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.1', '2.8', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.3', '2.5', '4.9', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.1', '2.8', '4.7', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.4', '2.9', '4.3', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.6', '3.0', '4.4', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.8', '2.8', '4.8', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.7', '3.0', '5.0', '1.7', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.0', '2.9', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.7', '2.6', '3.5', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.5', '2.4', '3.8', '1.1', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.5', '2.4', '3.7', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.8', '2.7', '3.9', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.0', '2.7', '5.1', '1.6', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.4', '3.0', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.0', '3.4', '4.5', '1.6', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.7', '3.1', '4.7', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.3', '2.3', '4.4', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.6', '3.0', '4.1', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.5', '2.5', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.5', '2.6', '4.4', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.1', '3.0', '4.6', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.8', '2.6', '4.0', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.0', '2.3', '3.3', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.6', '2.7', '4.2', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.7', '3.0', '4.2', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.7', '2.9', '4.2', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['6.2', '2.9', '4.3', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['5.1', '2.5', '3.0', '1.1', 'Iris-versicolor'], ['5.7', '2.8', '4.1', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'],
     ['6.3', '3.3', '6.0', '2.5', 'Iris-virginica'], ['5.8', '2.7', '5.1', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['7.1', '3.0', '5.9', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.3', '2.9', '5.6', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.5', '3.0', '5.8', '2.2', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.6', '3.0', '6.6', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['4.9', '2.5', '4.5', '1.7', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.3', '2.9', '6.3', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.7', '2.5', '5.8', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.2', '3.6', '6.1', '2.5', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.5', '3.2', '5.1', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.4', '2.7', '5.3', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.8', '3.0', '5.5', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica'], ['5.7', '2.5', '5.0', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['5.8', '2.8', '5.1', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.4', '3.2', '5.3', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.5', '3.0', '5.5', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.7', '3.8', '6.7', '2.2', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['7.7', '2.6', '6.9', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.0', '2.2', '5.0', '1.5', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.9', '3.2', '5.7', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'], ['5.6', '2.8', '4.9', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['7.7', '2.8', '6.7', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.3', '2.7', '4.9', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.7', '3.3', '5.7', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.2', '3.2', '6.0', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.2', '2.8', '4.8', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.1', '3.0', '4.9', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.4', '2.8', '5.6', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.2', '3.0', '5.8', '1.6', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['7.4', '2.8', '6.1', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.9', '3.8', '6.4', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.4', '2.8', '5.6', '2.2', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.3', '2.8', '5.1', '1.5', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.1', '2.6', '5.6', '1.4', 'Iris-virginica'], ['7.7', '3.0', '6.1', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.3', '3.4', '5.6', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.4', '3.1', '5.5', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.0', '3.0', '4.8', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.9', '3.1', '5.4', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.7', '3.1', '5.6', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.9', '3.1', '5.1', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['5.8', '2.7', '5.1', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.8', '3.2', '5.9', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.7', '3.3', '5.7', '2.5', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.7', '3.0', '5.2', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.3', '2.5', '5.0', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica'], ['6.5', '3.0', '5.2', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'],
     ['6.2', '3.4', '5.4', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica'], ['5.9', '3.0', '5.1', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']]

for i in range(len(iris_data_set[0]) - 1):
    str_column_to_float(iris_data_set, i)
# convert class column to integers
str_column_to_int(iris_data_set, len(iris_data_set[0]) - 1)
# evaluate algorithm
n_folds = 5
scores = evaluate_algorithm(iris_data_set, naive_bayes, n_folds)
print('Scores: %s' % scores)
print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f%%' % (sum(scores) / float(len(scores))))
```